# Disk status on Dell Powervault 1200 attached storage?

Tags: redhat, storage, dell, dell-powervault

I have a RHEL box with direct attached storage (Dell Powervault 1200) containing 10 disks in RAID 10.  There are two logical volumes set up on the server.  I am wondering how to determine the health of the drives from the operating system.  How can I determine if there is a drive that is in degraded mode from the operating system?  Are there tools that Dell provides to monitor the drives?

Answer (score 1):

How's the MD1200 connected to the server -- Dell PERC (5e/6e/H800) or similar RAID card, or is it a SAS HBA (and software RAID)?

If it's using a RAID controller, the management software that comes with it should handle drive health notifications. (For a Dell card, that's part of OpenManage Server Administrator -- although I've not tried to use that on a non-Dell host system).

You can also use utilities like smartmontools directly with [many RAID controllers](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/Supported_RAID-Controllers) (including the PERC), much like you would with a SAS HBA that presents the disks individually. There are Nagios plugins that inteface with the MegaCLI tools (for LSI-based cards like the PERC) -- and similar for other cards -- that also pull health information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in a supported configuration, you're nearly guaranteed to be able to monitor this from Open Manage Server Administrator. You can see RAID LUN status, individual disk health status, and even export RAID controller module logs to view error and event history.

OMSA 7.2 for RHEL 6:
http://ftp.us.dell.com/FOLDER01184959M/1/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-LX-7.2.0-6945.RHEL6.x86_64.tar.gz

OMSA 7.2 for RHEL 5:
http://ftp.us.dell.com/FOLDER01184956M/1/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-LX-7.2.0-6945.RHEL5.x86_64.tar.gz

Other versions available here:
http://ftp.us.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/poweredge-r710.html